# PayPal checkout broken on Safari

Tags: paypal

I've encountered a significant issue with PayPal checkout on my website, specifically when using Safari on both macOS and iOS. Whenever a customer attempts to checkout using Safari, they're met with a blank white page instead of the usual checkout flow. This issue doesn't occur with other browsers like Chrome or Firefox.

The problematic page link begins https://www.paypal.com/webapps/hermes?token=1JE ...

It is a recent issue, though I don't know when it started.

This issue is having a serious impact on my business, as it prevents customers using Safari from purchasing. Upon researching, I found that a few other e-commerce site owners have faced similar issues, so at least I am not alone.

Does anyone here have experience with this problem?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Looks like a question for PayPal and Apple